# adding int values to each other instead of overwriting them in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to make a simple billing system for a restaurant.
This shows the menu to the user and lets them choose, add an Item or quit.
In the end, it prints the bill.

The issue I'm facing is, I want the user to be able to add an item again with the item's number instead of overwriting the value.

Below code is my attempt which doesn't return anything.

```java
public void addOrder(String meal, int quantity,
                     String[] dish, double[] cost) {

    for (int i = 0; i < orderedFood.size(); i++) {
        // look if food item already exists, update quantity of it by
        // adding the previous value of the item to the new amount
        if (orderedFood.get(i).contains(meal)) {
            int oldQuantity = orderedQuantity.get(i);
            orderedQuantity.set(i, oldQuantity + quantity);
            break;
        } else {
            // if theres no item of this type yet, create a new one
            orderedFood.add(meal);
            orderedQuantity.add(quantity);
        }
    }
```

The code below shows how the food object gets created, and how the program works.

```java
public static void Order() {
    String[] dish = {"Sandwich", "Coffee", "Salad"};
    double[] cost = {6.5, 3.2, 4.0};

    for (int i = 0; i < dish.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\n" + dish[i] + ": " + cost[i] + "€.");
    }
    System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to order? \n\n");
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);


    List<String> dishList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dish));
    // check if item exists
    String menuItemTemp = myObj.nextLine();
    String menuItem = "";
    if (dishList.contains(menuItemTemp)) {
        System.out.println("\nOkay.\n");

        menuItem = menuItemTemp;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error 404 Not Found.");
        Order();
    }


    System.out.println("\nHow many? \n");
    int userQuant = myObj.nextInt();

    Bill myBill = new Bill();
    myBill.addOrder(menuItem, userQuant, dish, cost);

    System.out.println("\nOrder more? 1 - Yes. 2 - No. \n");
    Scanner menuScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menuScanner = menuScan.nextInt();

    switch (menuScanner) {
        // if another order is to be made
        case 1:
            System.out.println("\nOkay.");
            Order();
            break;
        // output and end of program
        case 2:
            myBill.getOrder();
            System.out.println(Math.round(myBill.getTotal() * 100.00) / 100.00 + "€\n");
            System.out.println("\nThanks for ordering!\n");
            // close scanners
            menuScan.close();
            myObj.close();
            // end 
            System.exit(1);
    }
```

Any nudge in the right direction would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So I would've left a comment if could've however I don't have enough reputation for that yet. I'm not sure what your `myBill.getTotalOrder()` function is. My first thought here without seeing more of your source code to understand your design would be to just make a Meal object that tracks its name, how much it is, and how many times it was ordered. Then during your `getTotalOrder()` you could just loop through each meal and add up the total.

Answer (score 1):

The error is the premature *else*. When not already present, you need to walk the entire *for* loop before knowing that there is no match.
If you do `return` instead of `break` you can treat the *not-found* case after the *for*.

```
public void addOrder(String meal, int quantity,
                     String[] dish, double[] cost) {

    for (int i = 0; i < orderedFood.size(); i++) {
        // look if food item already exists, update quantity of it by
        // adding the previous value of the item to the new amount
        if (orderedFood.get(i).contains(meal)) {
            int oldQuantity = orderedQuantity.get(i);
            orderedQuantity.set(i, oldQuantity + quantity);
            return;
        }
    }
    // if theres no item of this type yet, create a new one
    orderedFood.add(meal);
    orderedQuantity.add(quantity);
}
```

Of course

1. `for`
2. `orderedFood.get(i).contains(meal)`
3. `int oldQuantity = orderedQuantity.get(i);`
4. `orderedQuantity.set(i, oldQuantity + quantity);`

hints that an other data structure might be better:

```
Map<String, Integer> ordered = new HashMap<>(); // Meal to quantity.

public void addOrder(String meal, int quantity,
                     String[] dish, double[] cost) {
    ordered.merge(meal, quantity, Integer::sum);
}
```

That is map the meal names to the total quantity. Indices are irrelevant.

`Map.merge` works as follows:

```
merge(K key, V value, (Value oldv, Value newv) -> resultv)
```

If newv is null, a remove is done.
Otherwise:

The lambda is called with an (possibly accumulating) old value, and the passed value.

```
if (oldv == null)
    put(key, newv);
else
    put(key, oldv + newv); // newv == value
```

`Integer::sum` is the same as `(x, y) -> x + y`.